# Time complexity of this code confusing me

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, big-o

I'm struggling to understand the concepts of calculating time complexity. I have this code in C, why does the time complexity is O(n) and not O(n log n)?
The first loop is running for maximum of 3 iteration, the outer for loop is in logarithmic complexity and each iteration of it doing linear time.

```
int f2 (int n)
{
    int j, k, cnt=0;
    do 
    {
        ++n;
    } while (n%3);

    for (j=n; j>0; j/=3)
    {
        k=j;
        while (k>0)
        {
            cnt++;
            k-=3;
        }
    }

    return cnt;
}
```

Why do we neglecting the log time?

Comment: Calculate the sum n + n/3 + n/9 + n/27 + ... +1.

Comment: ok so when an algorithm runs for O (n log n)? how can I improve in those calculations?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by improving. You do this calculation and find out the complexity of this algorithm. For a different algorithm you need a different calculation.

Answer (score 1):

```
T = (n+n/3+n/9+...+1)
3*T - T = 3*n-1
T = 1.5*n-0.5
```

it's O(n)

Answer (score 1):

It is a common beginner's mistake to reason as follows:

- the outer loop follows a decreasing geometric progression, so it iteratess O(log n) times.
- the inner loop follows an arithmetic progression, so its complexity is O(n).
- hence the global complexity is O(n+n+n+...)=O(n log n).

The mistake is due to the lack of rigor in the notation. The correct approach is

- the outer loop follows a decreasing geometric progression, so it iterates O(log n) time.
- the inner loop follows an arithmetic progression, so its complexity is O(j) (*not O(n) !*), where j decreases geometrically.
- hence the global complexity is O(n+n/3+n/9+...)=O(n).

Answer (score 0):

The time complexity of you program is `O(n)`.
Because the total number of calculations is : `log(n)/log(3) + 2 * (n/3 + n/9 + n/27 + ... < log(n) + n/2 < 2*n`